# Can floor constructions be placed under furniture, or do you have to move it first?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Is it possible in Dwarf Fortress to add floor constructions without having to move furniture that is already occupying the same space? How should I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "add floor" and "move furniture" here. Are you asking about how to build a ceiling, or if furnitures can support floors without them caving in?

Comment: @YiJiang'sEvilClone You can build floor constructions, sort of laminating over the existing natural floors. It's not obvious in-game that it's even possible, but this question makes a lot more sense once you've discovered that you can do that.

Answer (score 8):

No, if you've already built furniture you can't then build a floor tile underneath it.

You'll need to dismantle the furniture first, build the floor, then rebuild the furniture. Also don't bother engraving the stone first if you're going to floor over it, building a floor (or furniture) over an engraving destroys the engraving, which can lead to unhappy thoughts if you accidentally deface someone's masterwork.

On the other hand, smoothing out the stone beforehand is useful as free practice for your engravers.

Comment: Building furniture won't destroy engravings. Constructions replace the floor on a tile, but the floor still exists under furniture, and the engraving can be examined. A simple example is the door, where you can still see that the floor is engraved.